# Can I use the simple past tense twice in a sentence?

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-simple

Is it correct to say

> She saw Henry when she turned on the television

Or should I say

> She saw Henry when she was turning on the television?

And should I say

> I met Anne when I went to the supermarket?

Or will it be

> I met Anne when I was going to the supermarket?

Comment: We are more likely to use past tense for a brief action and past progressive/continuous for a lengthy one. e.g. *She saw Henry when she turned on the television* and *She saw Henry when she was hanging out the washing*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The usage changes the meaning, but both sentences are grammatically correct.This applies to both the examples you've given.

I met Anne when I went to the supermarket.

suggests that you could have met Anne inside the supermarket.

I met Anne when I was going to the supermarket.

suggests that you were in the process of going to the supermarket; you weren't inside it.